# É incomum ter uma classe chamada mysqli o método getInstance() retornar o Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined

Tags: php, pdo

Olá estou fazendo um sistema para buscar listar os dados no banco de dados pelo mês só que ele dar o seguinte erro

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli::getInstance()

sendo que no meu vê está tudo certo.

esse é a query .

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class Usuario {
    private $connection = null;

    public function __construction($connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function carregaSetores($data) {
        try {
            $Query = "SELECT 
                    s.nome,
                    s.snome,
                    s.telefone,
                    s.refeicao,
                    s.bebida,
                    s.data,
                    s.hora,
                    s.npessoa,
                    s.nmesa,
                FROM pedido 
            ";

            $p_sql = mysql::getInstance()->prepare($Query);
            $_retorno = array(); 

            if ($p_sql->execute()) {
                while ($_result = $p_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
                    $_retorno[] = $_result; 
                }
            }

            return $_retorno;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
    ?>
```

e essa  é o código que gerar o relatório.

```
<?php

                require('config.php');
                require('usuario.php');


                $data    = $_POST["data"];                 
                $Usuario = new Usuario($dbConnetion);
                $listaDados = $Usuario->carregaSetores($data);



                   if(!empty($listaDados)){

                   foreach($listaDados as  $value){
              //echo "<pre>"; print_r($value); exit;
                 echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value["nome"] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value["snome"] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value["telefone"] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td>". $value["refeicao"] ."</td>";
                 echo "<td>". $value["bebida"] ."</td>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value["data"] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td><center>". $value["hora"] ."</center></td>";
                 echo "<td>". $value["npessoa"] ."</td>";
                 echo "<td>". $value["nmesa"] ."</td>";
                 echo "</tr >";

                                   }
    }


     ?>
```

e o que faz conexão com o banco de dados

```
<?php

    // Creating a database connection

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    // Selecting a database 

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "peixaria");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

?>
```

o erro estaria nessa linha

> $p_sql = mysql::getInstance()->prepare($Query);

Comment: É incomum ter uma classe chamada `mysqli` o método `getInstance()` retornar o que? poder colocar ele na pergunta.

Comment: coloquei isso como pergunta .

Comment: Desconheço essa função `mysqli::getInstance`, tenho certeza que não é nativa do php, portanto deve ser uma classe que pegou em algum lugar ou você criou inventou, de qualquer forma você chama isso de `mysqli`, mas a exception esperada é `PDOException`, até aonde sei Mysqli não é banco é uma API (extensão) do php para acessar o banco de dados mysql.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade é $p_sql = mysql::getInstance()->prepare($Query);

Comment: @allanaraujo ainda sim isso não existe nativamente no PHP, e portanto sem o código não tem como sabermos de fato o que ocorreu.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já coloquei o código . só queria gerar o relatório .

Comment: Infelizmente continuo não vendo de onde vem esse código `mysql::getInstance`, o que você colocou foi a classe Usuario e um foreach, mas o código aonde declarou a função `getInstance` e a classe `mysql` não estão na pergunta. Elas existem mesmo? Se não existir este é a resposta do teu problema.

Comment: Pelo teu código do config.php, você  está misturando PDO com mysqli, com funções que não existe, ou seja você está programando aleatóriamente sem entender como funcionam e sem ler a documentação, apenas copiando códigos aleatorios e misturando as coisas que nada fazem sentido, não é de se esperar que não funcione. Isso é uma critica construtiva, não saia fazendo as coisas sem ler a doc (http://php.net) e ver os exemplos lá e entende-los.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 3):

Não mistura o MySQLi com PDO, use um ou outro mas não os dois. Conforme os comentários e documentação não existe nenhum método `getInstance()` na classe `mysqli`.

O código está mais para o PDO que o MySQLi então para corrigir o problema o primeiro passo é criar uma conexão PDO. No arquivo `config.php` remova as instruções MySQLi e troque por:

```
$dbConnetion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=peixaria;', 'root', '');
```

Na classe Usuario modifique o método `carregaSetores()` remova o `getInstance()` e a propriedade `connection` para enviar as consultas para o banco.

Mude:

```
$p_sql = mysql::getInstance()->prepare($Query);
```

Para:

```
$p_sql = $this->connection->prepare($Query);
```